# Calculating percentages in C

Tags: c, function, integer

I am trying to find out how percentages are calculated within C, and specifically I am trying to find out how much taxes you get from user input, if the tax would be 21%.

But after trying the code in the terminal with input : 130,
which means I want 21% of 130$, it gives me a negative value of -858993459

How do Ifix this or where did I go wrong?

All of my google searches come up empty too, but probably because I am not using the correct phrasing so all info is welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double get_tax_amount(double price_including_taxes)
{
  return price_including_taxes *0.21;
}

int main()
{
  printf("What was your price? ");
  double price;
  scanf("%d", &price);
  printf("The tax price is: %d", get_tax_amount (price));      
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%lf", &price);` and `printf("The tax price is: %f\n", get_tax_amount(price));`

Comment: what's the difference between the two? could you explain why i would have to use %lf instead of %d ?

Comment: Your book / instructor should make it all clear. If you want to read the spec ==> [here's an HTMLized freely available version of a draft of the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: `%d` is for `int` and `%lf` in `scanf` is for `double`. It's in your C text book. And if you don't have one, it's time to get one.

Comment: @pmg I'm not sure if the C11 standard is suitable for beginners.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you didn't get some warnings from your compiler you should turn up warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra` to achieve that.

Comment: @11thJester: not sure you really want to understand how percentages are computed in C. This has nothing to do with C. C has nothing specific about computing percentages, it does it the same way as other languages do. I think you are rather trying to understand how C program works, with an exemple computing a percentage. You might want to edit your post (you can do that in Stack Overflow) to better explain your issue. Welcome on S.O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using the wrong conversion specifier in both `scanf` and `printf`.  To read a `double` value with `scanf` you need to use `%lf` and to print a `double` value with `printf` you need to use `%f`.

Because of how those functions work, they don’t know the number, type, or order of arguments you’ve actually passed to them - they just see a sludge of bytes on the stack or a sea of argument registers.  The only way for them to know what arguments they should *expect* is through what you specify in the format string.

`%d` is used to read and print `int` types, `%c` for individual characters, `%s` for strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try "%lf" instead of "%d". "%d" is expecting an integer, which conflicts with variable type "double".

Answer (score 0):

The variable type `double` should use `%lf` in `scanf` function, and `%f` in `printf` function.